# How to create a TCP connection using javascript in a browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, tcp

It is easy to create an [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request to obtain resources from an HTTP server. But I am trying to find a way to **create a TCP connection to a server to obtain certain resources**, in the browser.

HTTP works over TCP, so I think that the way **AJAX creates an HTTP request**, the modules they use can be used to do the same, since a TCP connection has to be established before creating an HTTP request.

So, I want to know how does the AJAX library create an HTTP request and what does it use so that I can do the same in my code.

Comment: what is this "AJAX library" you refer to? Do a search for "web sockets" - this will be the closest to what you possibly need

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will probably refuse to do this, for good security reasons.

When you visit a web page that contains javascript, that code gets pulled down and starts to run inside your browser (assuming you have allowed javascript).  That's handy, because it allows the website to be dynamic and do useful things for you.  But do you want to allow that javascript to read your hard drive?  I can assure you, you do NOT want that.  Do you want to allow it to make arbitrary TCP connections?  I can assure you that you don't want that either.  The browser WILL allow the code to go back to the same server and push and pull data - that's what the AJAX library is doing.  Nowadays browsers also allow javascript to initiate WebSocket connections, which is a little risky, but perhaps not as wide open as arbitrary TCP connections.

Comment: Okay. But how does the AJAX library initiate a connection?

Comment: Well, for example, from Wikipedia: "XMLHttpRequest (XHR) is an API ... [to] transfer data between a web browser and a web server. The object is provided by the browser's JavaScript environment."  Your answer is in the last sentence.  It's built into the internals of the browser.  You can't access TCP directly from javascript that's running within the browser.  Of course, you can get an open source browser and modify it to do what you want.  (Not recommended.)